# NoMethodError in Pages#home undefined method `environment' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

My relatively basic app was working fine then all of a sudden I ran into the following error. I have tried to solve this on my own with no luck. I thank any of you in advance for hoping me to solve this issue.

> NoMethodError in Pages#home undefined method `environment' for nil:NilClass (in /Users/kevindark/Site Name/app/assets/stylesheets/application.css.scss)

The exception page indicated the problem was extracted from the stylesheet_link_tag line of code below.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
<title><%= @title || "Site Name" %></title>
<%= favicon_link_tag 'favicon.ico' %>
<%= stylesheet_link_tag "application", media: "all", "data-turbolinks-track" => true %>
<%= javascript_include_tag "application", "data-turbolinks-track" => true %>
<%= csrf_meta_tags %>
```

Adding application.css.scss

```
/*
* Overwritten by RailsBricks
*
*= require_self
*/
@import "framework_and_overrides";
```

framework_and_overrides.css.scss available at the link below.

https://gist.github.com/kdark11/9537485

Comment: The problem is not on your view. Its in the stylesheet. Post your `application.css.scss`

Comment: @Vimsha - I added the css.scss files per your suggestion. Thanks for taking the time to review this to help me out.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This happened to my Rails app today as well.
It was driving me crazy and your question was the only hit on Google for the problem.
It turns out it was caused by the seemingly-harmless running of "bundle update" (just after adding a gem) which upgraded the 'sprockets' gem to '2.12.0'.

I forced sprockets to use the previous version with:

```
gem 'sprockets', '2.11.0'
```

in the Gemfile, then ran

```
bundle update
```

...and this solved it for me. edit: restart the server to finish, as the user below stated (thanks). Wow, if I had a dollar for every server restart during development! :-D
Major changes to resources and configuration always require a server restart.

2.12.0 was only released today, so I guess it has a bug or an incompatibility with some other gems we are using. I don't know for sure, I'm a bit of a n00b myself.
I hope this helps!
Edit: For the record, I can verify that faker and sass are not involved as they were installed/upgraded around the same time as the breaking update and I eliminated each. I can't speak for other gems but sprockets definitely is part of the problem here.

Comment: I also ran into this just yesterday and had run bundle install as well. This fixed it. Thank you.

Comment: Glad to help. I'm a long time lurker and was delighted to see a question I couldn't find an answer to that I managed to figure out. In fact it prompted a sign-up. I guess I was forced to use my brain when S.O. didn't bottle-feed me :)

Comment: Nice. That pretty much describes my relationship with this site as well. I don't remember what we did before it.

Comment: It fixed it for a rails app I upgraded for rails 4.0.4. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Downgrading to:

```
gem 'sprockets', '2.11.0'
```

...didn't work for me.

It turned out that I needed to lock slim as well:

```
gem 'sprockets', '2.11.0'
gem 'slim', '2.0.0'
```

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this problem while trying to get my app to work. After much trial and error the solution was indeed to update the sprockets gem with:

```
gem 'sprockets', '2.11.0'
```

and running

```
bundle update
```

Do not forget to restart your rails server, because at first I did not think the solution worked. All that I needed was to restart the server however.

Answer (score 0):

FWIW, I upgraded `sprockets` to `2.12.3` and I don't get the error anymore. I'm using Rails 4.1.8.

Answer (score 0):

I had this error using Rails 4.2.0 after upgrading from sprockets 2.12.3 to 3.0.1. I needed to actually add the sprockets gem in my Gemfile, and lock the version at 2.12.3.
In my Gemfile:

`gem 'sprockets', '2.12.3'`

This cleared everything up for me.